# Add a blur effect to a UIButton

Tags: swift, uikit, ios8

How can i make a button background get blurred?

Ill found out to get a blurred effect with this:

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
blur.frame = buttonForDisabling.frame
self.tableView.addSubview(blur)
```

This is working, but only makes a blur with the same frame as my button. I would like to have a button with a blurred background. Is that possible in iOS8?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done by creating the blur as you did and inserting it below the titleLabel of the UIButton. It's important to disable user interaction in order to allow the touches to not be intercepted by the the visual effect view and forwarded to the button.

**Swift 4.2:**

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style:
            UIBlurEffect.Style.light))
blur.frame = buttonForDisabling.bounds
blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //This allows touches to forward to the button.
buttonForDisabling.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 22):

If you are using a button with an image, bring the imageview to front:

```
buttonForDisabling.bringSubview(toFront: buttonForDisabling.imageView!)
```

or just use this extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIButton
{
    func addBlurEffect()
    {
        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        blur.frame = self.bounds
        blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)
        if let imageView = self.imageView{
            self.bringSubview(toFront: imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for reference if anyone is setting up constraints programmatically from ViewDidLoad this function will need to be called after as the buttons bounds will all be zero. That's why in other answers you may see constraints are added within this function so the blur view sizes accordinly.

Comment: Add clipsToBounds = true , if using cornerRadius

Answer (score 2):

Used Sherwin's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780749/9262593), but it didn't quite work for me as I use auto layout and my frame was .zero while this code runs. So I modified the code to use auto-layout and this now works for me:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    func addBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .regular, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0, padding: CGFloat = 0) {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
        blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blurView.backgroundColor = .clear
        if cornerRadius > 0 {
            blurView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            blurView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
        self.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)

        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true

        if let imageView = self.imageView {
            imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version of @tuvok's excellent response. I've also updated it and added options to control various aspects such as:

• `style`: The blur style

• `cornerRadius`: Allows you to make it rounded or a circle

• `padding`: This is useful if you want to use a cornerRadius but you want to make the size of the button larger for hit-testing.

```swift
extension UIButton {
    func addBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .regular, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0, padding: CGFloat = 0) {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
        blurView.frame = bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(horizontal: padding, vertical: padding))
        blurView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blurView.backgroundColor = .clear
        if cornerRadius > 0 {
            blurView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            blurView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
        self.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
        if let imageView = self.imageView{
            imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Love this version though UIEdgeInsets doesn't take `horizontal` and `vertical` as arguments in the latest version, from what I can tell. Also you have to put in a negative number for `padding` to get what you'd expect.